# why $ ⌊log_2N⌋ <=log_{3/2}N$

Tags: logarithms

Can anyone prove:

$ ⌊log_2N⌋ <=log_{3/2}N$

This question comes from the Binary Tree height calculation. If the number of element in a binary tree is N, the height of the tree is the floor of  $ log_2N $ which is smaller than $log_{3/2}N$.

video link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=La-xYKoKwjY&t=61s (time: 19:11)

Answer (score 1):

By definition of the greatest integer (floor) function: $$\;⌊\log_2N⌋ \le \log_2N \,$$

By monotonicity of the $\,\ln\,$ function, and given that $\,N\,$ is a positive integer, so $\,\ln N \ge 0\,$: $$\;\ln 2 \gt \ln \cfrac{3}{2} \gt \ln 1 = 0 \;\;\;\implies\;\;\;\log_2N = \cfrac{\ln N}{\ln 2}\lt \cfrac{\ln N}{\ln 3/2}=\log_{3/2}N\,$$

Comment: ⌊log2N⌋<=log2N<=log3/2N, such easy question, what was I thinking. Thank you!